# PHP MSSQL Table editor in browser

Tags: html, php, sql-server

I have a website running PHP, and a Microsoft SQL Database at the back end.
I want an end user to be able to edit a table within the SQL database.
I want them to be able to do this using a page on the website.

Rather than re-invent the wheel, I thought I'd ask if anyone knows of a decent but simple table editor designed for PHP & MSSQL. I want to integrate it into an existing design, so style & looks are unimportant.

My table looks like this, and this is currently the only way I can manage it:

```
INSERT INTO [T_RPT_VMWAREUSAGEREPORT_CUSTOM_VMLIST]
    ([LISTNAME],[VMNAME],[COMMENT])
VALUES
    ('CUSTOM_LIST01','Machine01','FIRST LIST'),
    ('CUSTOM_LIST01','Machine02','FIRST LIST'),
    ('CUSTOM_LIST01','Machine03','FIRST LIST'),
    ('CUSTOM_LIST02','Machine03','ANOTHER LIST'),
    ('CUSTOM_LIST02','Machine05','ANOTHER LIST')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org).

It's a litte Web App that supports MS-SQL and provides comprehensive database editing features (data and tables/meta data).

Just install it on a PC with XAMP or run it on a hosted server with PHP support.